# group by clause issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query in access and now I am trying to write the same in SQL Server I am getting following error:

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Procedure OQRY_STEP_1_1, Line 15
>   Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

My SQL Query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    ns11.SYS_ID,
    ns11.SUB_NET_ID,
    ns11.TEMP_ID,
    ns11.EQ_ID,
    ns11.NODE_NAME,
    ns11.EQ_NAME,
    ns11.VAR_NAME,
    ns11.VAR_SET,
    ns11.VAR_SUBSET,
    ns11.EQ_TYPE,
    ns11.RHS_RELN,
    ns11.RHS_OBJECT,
    ns11.EQ_TP_OFFSET,
    ns11.RHS_TP_OFFSET,
    ns11.RETAIN,
    nmte.RHS_VAR_SET,
    nmte.RHS_VAR_SUBSET,
    nmte.RHS_VAR_NAME,
    0 AS RHS_VAR_TYPE,
    CASE
        WHEN [asp].[VALUE] = NULL THEN 0
        ELSE [asp].[VALUE]
    END RHS_VALUE
INTO ##OT_STEP_1_1
FROM (##NT_STEP_1_1 ns11
    INNER JOIN ##NT_MASTER_TEMP_EQUATION nmte
        ON (ns11.SYS_ID = nmte.SYS_ID)
            (ns11.SUB_NET_ID = nmte.SUB_NET_ID)
        AND (ns11.TEMP_ID = nmte.TEMP_ID)
        AND (ns11.EQ_ID = nmte.EQ_ID)
        AND (ns11.NODE_NAME = nmte.NODE_NAME)
        AND (nmte.SYS_ID = ns11.SYS_ID)
        AND (nmte.SUB_NET_ID = ns11.SUB_NET_ID))
    LEFT JOIN AMST_SIM_PAR asp ON 
        (nmte.SYS_ID = asp.SYS_ID)
        AND (nmte.SUB_NET_ID = ns11.SUB_NET_ID)
        AND (nmte.RHS_VAR_NAME = asp.VAR_NAME)
GROUP BY
    ns11.SYS_ID,
    ns11.SUB_NET_ID,
    ns11.TEMP_ID,
    ns11.EQ_ID,
    ns11.NODE_NAME,
    ns11.EQ_NAME,
    ns11.VAR_NAME,
    ns11.VAR_SET,
    ns11.VAR_SUBSET,
    ns11.EQ_TYPE,
    ns11.RHS_RELN,
    ns11.RHS_OBJECT,
    ns11.EQ_TP_OFFSET,
    ns11.RHS_TP_OFFSET,
    ns11.RETAIN,
    nmte.RHS_VAR_SET,
    nmte.RHS_VAR_SUBSET,
    nmte.RHS_VAR_NAME,
    0,
    CASE
        WHEN [asp].[VALUE] = NULL THEN 0
        ELSE [asp].[VALUE]
    END
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN [asp].[VALUE] = NULL THEN 0
        ELSE [asp].[VALUE]
    END;
```

I am not sure why it is not taking 0 in the group by clause?

Comment: What's the purpose of `GROUP BY 0` ? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Are you missing an AND on the first two parts of your inner join between the SYS_ID and SUB_NET_ID parts?

Comment: My eyes are burning. Carriage returns, tabs, and aliases are your friends, trust me. :-)  So are readable table names, but you might not have control over that.

Comment: 23 questions, 0 votes cast, ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `GROUP BY ..., 0, ...` is the issue here. Try removing that `0` from there. There is no point grouping by a constant.

---

Sidenote:

```
CASE WHEN [AMST_SIM_PAR].[VALUE] = NULL
THEN 0
ELSE [AMST_SIM_PAR].[VALUE]
END
```

should be be written with `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL` or as:

```
COALESCE( [AMST_SIM_PAR].[VALUE], 0 )
```

Comment: No its not working I am still getting the error ...but I think the error is because of 0 in the group by.

Comment: Then remove that `0` from the `GROUP BY`!

Answer (score 1):

I think the constant '0' in your group by is the problem.

Are you using ANSI_NULLS?  SQL-92 defines "= NULL" or "<> NULL" to always return false.  Try changing "= NULL" to "IS NULL".

Also in your left join you have a criteria that doesn't match the outer table.  The inner join  already links SUB_NET_ID on those two tables so you can remove it from your left join.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not taking any aggregates, why not just use `DISTINCT` instead of repeating all that noise in the `GROUP BY`? Also the `ORDER BY` is not very useful because you are using `SELECT INTO`, which creates a new table, which by definition is an unordered set of rows. In order to get the data out of that table in the right "order" you should use an `ORDER BY` when you eventually select out of it. If you want the data optimized for joins or what have you after the table is created, create a clustered index after the `SELECT INTO`. Finally, why are you using ##global temp tables? You know that two users can't execute this code at the same time, right?

All that said, here is a much simpler and easier to read version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    n.SYS_ID, 
    n.SUB_NET_ID, 
    n.TEMP_ID, 
    n.EQ_ID, 
    n.NODE_NAME, 
    n.EQ_NAME, 
    n.VAR_NAME, 
    n.VAR_SET, 
    n.VAR_SUBSET, 
    n.EQ_TYPE, 
    n.RHS_RELN, 
    n.RHS_OBJECT, 
    n.EQ_TP_OFFSET, 
    n.RHS_TP_OFFSET, 
    n.RETAIN, 
    te.RHS_VAR_SET, 
    te.RHS_VAR_SUBSET, 
    te.RHS_VAR_NAME, 
    RHS_VAR_TYPE = 0, 
    RHS_VALUE = COALESCE(a.VALUE, 0)
INTO ##OT_STEP_1_1
FROM ##NT_STEP_1_1 AS n
INNER JOIN ##NT_MASTER_TEMP_EQUATION AS te
        ON n.SYS_ID = te.SYS_ID
        AND n.SUB_NET_ID = te.SUB_NET_ID 
        AND n.TEMP_ID = te.TEMP_ID 
        AND n.EQ_ID = te.EQ_ID
        AND n.NODE_NAME = te.NODE_NAME 
        AND te.SYS_ID = n.SYS_ID
        AND te.SUB_NET_ID = n.SUB_NET_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AMST_SIM_PAR AS a 
        ON te.SYS_ID = a.SYS_ID
        AND te.SUB_NET_ID = n.SUB_NET_ID
        AND te.RHS_VAR_NAME = a.VAR_NAME;
```